# Use Laravel project CSS on react component

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I currently have a blade file with my headers pointing to my css as one would normally do.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={{ asset("css/style-main.css") }}>
```

In this blade file I have a component which is being used for a drop down dynamic menu here:

```
<div id="reactApp"></div>
```

In my react component I have a className which points to a css class found in my blade file.

```
<div className="price">
```

The problem is my css is not displaying as it should.  It doesn't display at all for that matter.  I would expect it to display since it's in the parent blade file.  Do I have to attach the css file also in the react component for it to work?

Comment: No you dont. This should have worked. Check the link tag generated in the HTML and the contents of the style-main.css file to debug

Comment: Thank you I'll check it out @Paras